# Time window not working

Tags: python

I tested below code, but unfortunalty it is not working as expected.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()

if now.hour == 5 or (now.hour == 22):
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

The time window in upper example is only open between 5.00h and 5.59.59.
At 5.59h it still prints True,  but at 6.00h it prints False. 
I would like to have a working code where the time window is open between 5.00h and
22.00h. Any suggestions??

Thanks

Comment: I see that you are new so i will tell you this:
When someones answer helped you give then an upvote, i someones answer solved your problem accept their answer and upvote ;)

Answer (score 2):

just change your `if` :

```
if now.hour >= 5 and (now.hour < 22)
```

Now it will be from 5:00 till 21:59

Comment: It is 6.15h in Switzerland now.

Comment: It is 14:15 in Japan :D ,  I don't know why you told me the time but here is my local time XD

Comment: if I test code,  if now.hour >= 7 and now.minute <=30  or (now.hour < 8) it prints true, should it not print false??

Comment: still prints true  if (now.hour >= 7 and now.minute <=30) or (now.hour < 8), should print false until 7.30 and after print true until 8

Comment: now its 6.35 local time if I a put,  if (now.hour >= 6 and now.minute <=30) and (now.hour < 8)  it prints False but should print True.

Comment: so far all the suggestions have not helped to make a time window between 6.30h and 8.00h

Comment: if  ((now.hour >= 6 and now.minute >=30) and (now.hour < 8)) or ((now.hour >= 7) and (now.hour < 8))

Answer (score 0):

like this its working from 6.30h until 8.00h. a little bit complicated to understand, but working. Thank you again for helping

if ((now.hour >= 6 and now.minute >=30) and (now.hour < 8)) or ((now.hour >= 7) and (now.hour < 8)): 
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)